# Gradle removing comments and reformatting properties file

Tags: java, gradle, properties-file

When I am trying to edit a property within Gradle it re-formats my entire properties file and removes the comments. I am assuming this is because of the way Gradle is reading and writing to the properties file. I would like to just change a property and leave the rest of the properties file untouched including leaving the current comments in place and order of the values. Is this possible to do using Gradle 5.2.1?

I have tried to just use setProperty (which does not write to the file), used a different writer: `(versionPropsFile.withWriter { versionProps.store(it, null) } )`

and tried a different way to read in the properties file: `versionProps.load(versionPropsFile.newDataInputStream())`

Here is my current Gradle code:

```
   File versionPropsFile = file("default.properties");

   def versionProps = new Properties() 

   versionProps.load(versionPropsFile.newDataInputStream())

    int version_minor = versionProps.getProperty("VERSION_MINOR")
    int version_build = versionProps.getProperty("VERSION_BUILD")

    versionProps.setProperty("VERSION_MINOR", 1)
    versionProps.setProperty("VERSION_BUILD", 2)

    versionPropsFile.withWriter { versionProps.store(it, null) }
```

Here is a piece of what the properties file looks like before gradle touches it:

```
# Show splash screen at startup (yes* | no)
SHOW_SPLASH = yes

# Start in minimized mode (yes | no*)
START_MINIMIZED = no

# First day of week (mon | sun*)
# FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = sun

# Version number
# Format: MAJOR.MINOR.BUILD

VERSION_MAJOR = 1
VERSION_MINOR = 0
VERSION_BUILD = 0

# Build value is the date

BUILD = 4-3-2019
```

Here is what Gradle does to it:

```
#Wed Apr 03 11:49:09 CDT 2019
DISABLE_L10N=no
LOOK_AND_FEEL=default
ON_MINIMIZE=normal
CHECK_IF_ALREADY_STARTED=YES
VERSION_BUILD=0
ASK_ON_EXIT=yes
SHOW_SPLASH=yes
VERSION_MAJOR=1
VERSION_MINOR=0
VERSION_BUILD=0
BUILD=04-03-2019
START_MINIMIZED=no
ON_CLOSE=minimize
PORT_NUMBER=19432
DISABLE_SYSTRAY=no
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Gradle issue per se. The default `Properties` object of Java does not preserve any layout/comment information of properties files. You can use  [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html), for example, to get layout-preserving properties files.

Here’s a self-contained sample `build.gradle` file that loads, changes and saves a properties file, preserving comments and layout information (at least to the degree that is required by your example file):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.4'
    }
}

import org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfigurationLayout

task propUpdater {
    doLast {
        def versionPropsFile = file('default.properties')

        def config = new PropertiesConfiguration()
        def fileHandler = new FileHandler(config)
        fileHandler.file = versionPropsFile
        fileHandler.load()

        // TODO change the properties in whatever way you like; as an example,
        // we’re simply incrementing the major version here:
        config.setProperty('VERSION_MAJOR',
            (config.getProperty('VERSION_MAJOR') as Integer) + 1)

        fileHandler.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason gradle is refusing to recognise the package org.apache.commons.configuration2

Comment: @Mark, I could just run this exact sample with both Gradle 6.9.1 and 7.3.3 without any issues. Are you sure that you have the `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.4` as a _buildscript_ dependency (not a project dependency)?